# Finding Volume with complex shapes

Tags: calculus

My question is about finding volumes of complex shapes. I've got a $3$D plane where I have, for example, $y=x$ and $x=z^2$. I want to find the volume of the shape which is created from that line and parabola (like, every point on the line is connected to the corresponding points on the parabola). I tried things but it seems they don't work out.

> [image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is each point on the line connected to points on the parabola, specifically?

Comment: If the cross sections parallel to the $yz$-plane are triangles, you integrate the areas of the triangles wrt $x$. One-half base times height, with base & height in terms of $x$.

Comment: Similar to John Wayland Bales, if the cross -sections are parabolas, you integrate that wrt $x$. But we already know (from Archimedes) that the area of the parabola is 4/3 times that of the triangle (or you could integrate it yourself from $y(z)=x-z^2$).